# update statement is not working in instead of trigger oracle11g

Tags: sql, database, triggers, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTMARK
(
    STUD_ROLLNO NUMBER(10),
    CLASS_NAME VARCHAR2(10),
    MARK1 NUMBER(5),
    MARK2 NUMBER(5),
    TOTAL NUMBER(5)
);
```

A)Write a PL/SQL Trigger to update total in 'studentMark' table
when insert takes place in the same table.
QUERY:

```
CREATE VIEW STUDENTMARK_VIEW
AS SELECT * FROM STUDENTMARK;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOTAL_TRIG INSTEAD OF INSERT ON STUDENTMARK_VIEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO STUDENTMARK (STUD_ROLLNO,CLASS_NAME,MARK1,MARK2)
  VALUES (:NEW.STUD_ROLLNO,:NEW.CLASS_NAME,:NEW.MARK1,:NEW.MARK2);
UPDATE STUDENTMARK SET TOTAL = :new.mark1+:new.mark2
  WHERE stud_rollno = :new.STUD_ROLLNO;
END;
/

truncate table studentmark;
INSERT INTO STUDENTMARK (STUD_ROLLNO,CLASS_NAME,MARK1,MARK2) 
  VALUES (1,'CSE_B',100,100);
SELECT * FROM STUDENTMARK;
```

I tried many times. It is inserting the values of mark1 and mark2 but not updating the total - what's the error?

Comment: Your trigger is on STUDENTMARK_VIEW! If you want that the trigger is called when you insert a record on STUDENTMARK table, you must define the trigger on STUDENTMARK table!

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting into the table, not the view, so the trigger event isn't occurring. It does what you expect if you do insert into the view:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENTMARK_VIEW (STUD_ROLLNO,CLASS_NAME,MARK1,MARK2) 
  VALUES (1,'CSE_B',100,100);

SELECT * FROM STUDENTMARK;

STUD_ROLLNO CLASS_NAME      MARK1      MARK2      TOTAL
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 CSE_B             100        100        200
```

You don't need separate insert and update statements in the trigger, you can calculate the total during the insert:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENTMARK (STUD_ROLLNO,CLASS_NAME,MARK1,MARK2,TOTAL)
  VALUES (:NEW.STUD_ROLLNO,:NEW.CLASS_NAME,:NEW.MARK1,:NEW.MARK2,
    :NEW.MARK1+:NEW.MARK2);
```

The view seems a bit pointless though as it exactly matches the table. And as you've seen, there is nothing stopping inserting directly into the table and skipping the calculation. It would make *some* sense if you planned to allow other people to insert into the view but not in the table, via appropriate granted privileges, but the owner can still always insert directly into the table

If you want the total to be calculated you could either leave that column out of the base table and calculate it in the view:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTMARK
(
    STUD_ROLLNO NUMBER(10),
    CLASS_NAME VARCHAR2(10),
    MARK1 NUMBER(5),
    MARK2 NUMBER(5)
);

CREATE VIEW STUDENTMARK_VIEW AS
SELECT STUD_ROLLNO, CLASS_NAME, MARK1, MARK2, MARK1 + MARK2 AS TOTAL
FROM STUDENTMARK;

INSERT INTO STUDENTMARK (STUD_ROLLNO,CLASS_NAME,MARK1,MARK2) 
  VALUES (1,'CSE_B',100,100);

SELECT * FROM STUDENTMARK;

STUD_ROLLNO CLASS_NAME      MARK1      MARK2
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 CSE_B             100        100 

SELECT * FROM STUDENTMARK_VIEW;

STUD_ROLLNO CLASS_NAME      MARK1      MARK2      TOTAL
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 CSE_B             100        100        200
```

Or use a virtual column on the base table:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTMARK
(
    STUD_ROLLNO NUMBER(10),
    CLASS_NAME VARCHAR2(10),
    MARK1 NUMBER(5),
    MARK2 NUMBER(5),
    TOTAL NUMBER(5) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MARK1 + MARK2)
);

INSERT INTO STUDENTMARK (STUD_ROLLNO,CLASS_NAME,MARK1,MARK2) 
  VALUES (1,'CSE_B',100,100);

SELECT * FROM STUDENTMARK;

STUD_ROLLNO CLASS_NAME      MARK1      MARK2      TOTAL
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 CSE_B             100        100        200
```

Or keep the physical column and have a trigger on the table that does the calculation; but as you're on 11g using a virtual column is simpler and safer.